# Kafka - Confluent - Java Version Support

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am looking at Apache Kafka v2.0.0 and I can't figure out what version of java it supports (OpenJDK or Oracle JDK's new lifecycle)? So far I have seen conflicting documentations. For example:
In Apache Kafka Documentation page it says: Java 1.8, however in their release notes for v2.0 I see the bug fixes and improvement like:

> - [KAFKA-6855] - Kafka fails to start with Java 10 due to faulty Java version detection
> - [KAFKA-5907] - Support aggregatedJavadoc in Java 9

Confluent v5.x [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html) says they don't support 9 or 10

> Java 1.9 and 1.10 are not currently supported in Confluent Platform. Later versions of Confluent Platform will support these Java versions.

but their CTO in Nov 2017 on [this page](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-goes-1-0/) says

> "We now support Java 9, leading, significantly faster TLS and CRC32C implementations"

Knowing Oracle have taken a different lifecycle with their LTS OracleJDK and they are dropping support for 1.8. What is Kafka's decision in terms of java support? I can't figure it out from documentation. What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a difference between "supported" and being able to "run with". The later being the JIRA tickets. The former being used an enterprise support term.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Kafka 2.1.0 and newer support Java 11:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7264

There was an outdated documentation page that has been fixed (the website will be updated soon):

https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/9080

Answer (score 1):

### Apache Kafka v2.0.0

[Apache Kafka official documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#java) is quite clear on that:

> From a security perspective, we recommend you use the latest released
>   version of JDK 1.8 as older freely available versions have disclosed
>   security vulnerabilities. LinkedIn is currently running JDK 1.8 u5
>   (looking to upgrade to a newer version) with the G1 collector.

Also, [notable changes in 2.0.0](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_200_notable) section mentions the following:

> Support for Java 7 has been dropped, Java 8 is now the minimum version
>   required.

Oracle JDK is recommended but openJDK or Zulu should work fine for most cases as well.

### Confluent Platform 5.0.x

For [Confluent Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#java) in particular,

> Java 1.9 and 1.10 are not currently supported in Confluent Platform.
>   Later versions of Confluent Platform will support these Java versions.

and the minimum recommended version for Confluent 5.0.x (that comes with Kafka `v2.0.0`) is JDK 1.8 → u31 or later.

Comment: I've already mentioned the these documentations in my question. My question revolves around the contradictions these documention are giving. please read the question fully again.

Comment: Confluent is a different Kafka 'distribution'. Are you using Confluent Kafka or vanilla Apache Kafka?

Comment: I understand the difference, however, my questions is around the end of life of Oracle JDK support for 1.8. Both distributions haven't addressed the new Java lifecycle.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can still use openJDK.

Answer (score 0):

The blog by Neha Narkhede only refers to Kafka, not Confluent Platform.  Like most companies with model of selling services to an open-source project, Confluent's add-ons address their customers' needs.  Since most customers are probably running 1.8, there is no business need to support 9 or 10 yet.

However, the open-source project has to address the EOL support of Java.  You can see this in the JIRAs.

- [KAFKA-4501 - Support Java 9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4501)
- [HADOOP-11123 - Fix Java 9 incompatibilies in Hadoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11123)

Answer (score 0):

Latest update as of Aug 2021. As per this: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html

> Java 8 and Java 11 are supported in this version of Confluent Platform. Starting with Confluent Platform 5.0, the minimum required version is
> Java 8. Java 7 or earlier versions are no longer supported. Java 9 and
> 10 are not supported in Confluent Platform as those versions are
> short-term rapid release versions.
>
> Confluent Platform 5.0 maps to Apache Kafka 2.0.x

Answer (score 0):

Confluent-7.2.0 supports java 8 and java 11. If you have any of them all you need to do is to set your system wide java version as 11 or 8 by running the below mentioned command in your terminal.

```
 jenv global 11.0
```

Here I attach a link where you can learn how to manage with multiple version of java.. You can install multiple versions of java and switch between them according to your project needs. 
[how to manage multiple java versions](https://chamikakasun.medium.com/how-to-manage-multiple-java-version-in-macos-e5421345f6d0)